# Notepad and other programs trying to open in MicroSoft SharePoint

Tags: 2007

When I click to open notepad or microsoft word or other executable program, they are all opening MicroSoft SharePoint instead with a blank page except for a strange looking symbol on the page.   I uninstalled MicroSoft SharePoint and now my programs are opening normally.  How can I run MicroSoft SharePoint without it doing this (and why is this happening)?  I've uninstalled MS SharePoint and then reinstalled it and the same problem occurs.  Thanks!

Comment: When you say it "opens in SharePoint", how do you mean? What is it that you see?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what might be going on based on your description. It sounds like you must have installed SharePoint on your local machine (as opposed to a server). If you're doing that and are having this issue, then I'd wonder why you are installing SharePoint in the first place.